# How do I preview my web page on my dashboard?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, adminlte

I am creating a dashboard with the AdminLTE template, and I have a list section in which I can change the colors of the different sections of my web page.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to generate a preview of my web so that the administrator user of the dashboard can see the changes there.

I think it should not be easy, but I would like to know if there are different ways to achieve that, or if there is a plugin that is helpful.

Currently my project is done in HTML, Javascript and PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `iframe` to show the preview of your website in the admin dashboard.
Just add an `iframe` tag inside the dashboard panel like this,

```
<iframe src="https://www.your_website.com"></iframe>
```

**Tip**: To deal with browsers that do not support , add a text between the opening  tag and the closing  tag.

**Tip**: Use CSS to style the  (even to include scrollbars).

Comment: Thank you! One question, what do you mean by the first suggestion? Could you give me an example? Regards!

Comment: Not all browsers support the iframe tag specially the the old IE ones.